# Book suggestion to learn about differential equations with regular singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation, connections

I am looking for a suggestion, other than Deligne's *Equations Différentielles à Points Singuliers Réguliers*, but **covering more or less the same content**.

I am having trouble finding a down to earth treatment of the subject, and Deligne's book seems to be written in the style of Grothendieck's EGA, so, at least for me at this moment, is very dark.

To give a context, I am studying for a master’s degree, and as my first approach to a research I am working on Representation Theory, to be more specific on the representation theory for rational Cherednik algebras. I am reading some papers on the subject and many of them cite Deligne's book. Maybe I don't need a deep understanding of the subject, but I will feel more comfortable if I can understand it more deeply.

Comment: You may wish to take a look at Chapter 7 of JW Dettman's *Applied Complex Variables*.