# Reading roadmap for Deligne's Equations Differentielles a Points Singuliers Reguliers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, analytic-geometry, schemes, analytic-functions

I'm trying to read Deligne's book *Equations Differentielles a Points Singuliers Reguliers*. I have asked many people for alternatives to this book but it seems to be the only reference in the subject. In fact, I never got an answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495186/book-suggestion-to-learn-about-differential-equations-with-regular-singular-poin), even having bountied it.

Appart from the intrinsinc difficulty in the contents of the book, I have some background difficulties: I'm not familiar with the notions of analytic spaces and analytic varieties, and having not read the book yet, tt is possible I have more knowledge gaps.

Thus, I'm asking, if someone is familiar with the theory developed in this book, for suggestions for reading this book:

1. What I need to know before I can read the book and where can I learn those things? In particular: Where can I learn about analytic spaces and analytic varieties?
2. Are there complementary or supporting readings to clarify it's contents?

With respect to my background, I have knowledge of the basics of algebraic geometry, scheme theory, smooth manifolds, affine connections and other stuff.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For analytic spaces and analytic varieties, I would take a look at Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry*.